# Referring to 'these' in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Here's a JQuery function:

```
$("label[for='ch_c'], label[for='ch_ad']").click( function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('active') ){
        $('#box').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        $('#box').fadeOut(300);
    } 
});
```

I need `(this)` to refer to either of the two elements, so `#box` stays visible if either of them have class `active`. Currently, `(this)` only refers to the element that was actually clicked. Is there, in effect, a Jquery term for 'either of these'?

Comment: Could you please post some HTML-Code? I need to see your DOM-Structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `click` event handler (and any other event handlers for that matter), `this` will always refer to the element that received the event. You could simply reuse the elements matched by your selector:

```
var elems = $("label[for='ch_c'], label[for='ch_ad']");
elems.click( function(){ //Bind click event handler to matched elements
    if(elems.hasClass('active') ){ //If any elements have active class
        $('#box').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        $('#box').fadeOut(300);
    } 
});
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks James.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there, in effect, a Jquery term for 'either of these'?

No. You will have to do it by yourself. Use the same selector.

Answer (score 0):

NO. `this` will always refer to the DOM element which has trigger the event. You will have to explicitly select the element if you want to check for both the elements.

May be can store the matched element into a variable out the handler and use it inside the handler that way you don't have to find the elements everytime event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is. Your best option is to invoke the code on `this` and its sibling which you can hone into the correct sibling by referencing part of the element's ID.